# Cast to child interface

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have a method that return a interface reference `IInterfaceA`, and want to cast it to an `IInterfaceB` doing this:

```
IInterfaceA a = SomeMethodThatReturnAnIInterfaceA();
IInterfaceB b = (IInterfaceB)a;

public IInterfaceA : OtherInterfaceA, OtherInterfaceB {}
public IInterfaceB : IInterfaceB {}
```

But at runtime I got:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'OPCAutomation.OPCGroupClass' to interface
type 'SemaforosNNM.OPC.OPCDaGroup'. This operation failed because the
QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
'{70F93164-7F80-37E3-8EFB-DAB08298316E}' failed due to the following error: 
Interfaz no compatible (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

What are we missing here?

Comment: Well you're missing code that will compile, for starters.

Comment: There is no indication that two interferes are related. Read [mcve] guidance and[edit] post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the following line:

```
public interface IInterfaceB: IInterfaceB
```

is in reality:

```
public interface IInterfaceB : IInterfaceA
```

Let's put names that are easier to understand:

```
public interface IAnimal //IInterfaceA
public interface ICat : IAnimal //IInterfaceB
public interface IDog : IAnimal //another IInterfaceB

IAnimal someAnimal = GetMeADog();
ICat catAndDogsDontMix = (ICat)someAnimal; //ouch!
```

Do you understand now why you can't cast to a "child" interface?

What's strange though is that you are showing a runtime error; the code you've posted shouldn't even compile. Are you sure your code is reproing your issue correctly? Maybe `a` is typed `object`?